# Extracting strings from foldername

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell, I would like to extract just the 20191009 from this folder name `CNMC - Childrens National Medical Center Weekly20191009105726`
How can I do that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link and update your question accordingly. What did you investigate? Add also your code effort to the question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier, I'm new to Powershell and have not tried anything.

Comment: `$null = $foldername -match "\d{8}"; $matches[0]`. It would be more helpful if you supplied the code you are trying so a solution could be tailored to your needs.

Comment: Another option: `'CNMC - Childrens National Medical Center Weekly20191009105726' -replace '.+?(\d{8}).*', '$1'`